# Create URLs to modify Database in Drupal and IOS app

Tags: php, mysql, ios, url, drupal-7

I need to create a URLs to change (view/edit/remove/insert) elements in a Database external of Drupal. I know modify elements of a Database external from Drupal but my boss want unify the access at Database from Drupal and IOS app with a URL like:

http://*my-web*/*name-database*/insert/*name-table*/*data-to-insert*

or

http://*my-web*/modify-database?db=*name-database*&action=insert&table=*name-table*&data=*data-to-insert*

This URL should insert/show/delete/edit elements in a database and show confirm/error message.

How I do this? I need a module, a script,...?